# Programming and configuring the U-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, hardware, u-boot, device-tree

First of all, this question is related to the creation of embedded Operating System and, to be exact, with Linux Kernel + u-boot + FSBL + device tree + FS compiled to run on an arm A9.

**Context:**

After booting this (just created) OS upon a Zynq device (specifically, a Pynq Board), the Uart gives these messages:

```
No valid device tree binary found - please append one to U-Boot binary, use u-boot-dtb.bin or define CONFIG_OF_EMBED. For sandbox, use -d <file.dtb>
initcall sequence 04061cc0 failed at call 04045e9c (err=-1)
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

**Question:**

It is clear that the error is on the generation of the u-boot.elf: it tries to use a device tree that it is impossible to find but, in the BOOT folder, the device tree is present with the name  `devicetree.dtb`. What can cause this problem? Which configuration file can I try to modify to point to the right device tree? Any suggestions?

**Some details:**

Just to add more information,

1) the first stage bootloader seems to work fine and it prints:

```
Xilinx First Stage Boot Loader 
Release 2017.1  Jan 25 2018-18:26:02
Devcfg driver initialized 
Silicon Version 3.1
Boot mode is SD
SD: rc= 0
SD Init Done 
Flash Base Address: 0xE0100000
Reboot status register: 0x60600000
Multiboot Register: 0x0000C000
Image Start Address: 0x00000000
Partition Header Offset:0x00000C80
Partition Count: 4
Partition Number: 1
Header Dump
Image Word Len: 0x000F6EC0
Data Word Len: 0x000F6EC0
Partition Word Len:0x000F6EC0
Load Addr: 0x00000000
Exec Addr: 0x00000000
Partition Start: 0x000065D0
Partition Attr: 0x00000020
Partition Checksum Offset: 0x00000000
Section Count: 0x00000001
Checksum: 0xFFD14B7E
Bitstream
In FsblHookBeforeBitstreamDload function 
PCAP:StatusReg = 0x40000A30
PCAP:device ready
PCAP:Clear done
Level Shifter Value = 0xA 
Devcfg Status register = 0x40000A30 
PCAP:Fabric is Initialized done
PCAP register dump:
PCAP CTRL 0xF8007000: 0x4C00E07F
PCAP LOCK 0xF8007004: 0x0000001A
PCAP CONFIG 0xF8007008: 0x00000508
PCAP ISR 0xF800700C: 0x0802000B
PCAP IMR 0xF8007010: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP STATUS 0xF8007014: 0x00000A30
PCAP DMA SRC ADDR 0xF8007018: 0x00100001
PCAP DMA DEST ADDR 0xF800701C: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP DMA SRC LEN 0xF8007020: 0x000F6EC0
PCAP DMA DEST LEN 0xF8007024: 0x000F6EC0
PCAP ROM SHADOW CTRL 0xF8007028: 0xFFFFFFFF
PCAP MBOOT 0xF800702C: 0x0000C000
PCAP SW ID 0xF8007030: 0x00000000
PCAP UNLOCK 0xF8007034: 0x757BDF0D
PCAP MCTRL 0xF8007080: 0x30800100

DMA Done ! 

FPGA Done ! 
In FsblHookAfterBitstreamDload function 
Partition Number: 2
Header Dump
Image Word Len: 0x0001BB09
Data Word Len: 0x0001BB09
Partition Word Len:0x0001BB09
Load Addr: 0x04000000
Exec Addr: 0x04000000
Partition Start: 0x000FD490
Partition Attr: 0x00000010
Partition Checksum Offset: 0x00000000
Section Count: 0x00000001
Checksum: 0xF7EAF7E3
Application
Partition Number: 3
Header Dump
Image Word Len: 0x00000A05
Data Word Len: 0x00000A05
Partition Word Len:0x00000A05
Load Addr: 0x02A00000
Exec Addr: 0x00000000
Partition Start: 0x00118FA0
Partition Attr: 0x00000012
Partition Checksum Offset: 0x00000000
Section Count: 0x00000001
Checksum: 0xFD4E4FCD
Application
Handoff Address: 0x04000000
In FsblHookBeforeHandoff function 
SUCCESSFUL_HANDOFF
FSBL Status = 0x1
No valid device tree binary found - please append one to U-Boot binary, use u-boot-dtb.bin or define CONFIG_OF_EMBED. For sandbox, use -d <file.dtb>
initcall sequence 04061cc0 failed at call 04045e9c (err=-1)
### ERROR ### Please RESET the board ###
```

2) The only file I modified from the original U-boot repository is the `zynq-common.h`. I did it because I have to use the Linaro FS and not the default `initfsram`. Here the part of the file modified (of couse, as you can understand, I am using an SD-Card and the modification were done for the `sdboot`):

```
/* Default environment */
#ifndef CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS
#define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS   \
    "fit_image=fit.itb\0"       \
    "load_addr=0x2000000\0"     \
    "fit_size=0x800000\0"       \
    "flash_off=0x100000\0"      \
    "nor_flash_off=0xE2100000\0"    \
    "fdt_high=0x20000000\0"     \
    "initrd_high=0x20000000\0"  \
    "loadbootenv_addr=0x2000000\0" \
    "bootenv=uEnv.txt\0" \
    "bootenv_dev=mmc\0" \
    "loadbootenv=load ${bootenv_dev} 0 ${loadbootenv_addr} ${bootenv}\0" \
    "importbootenv=echo Importing environment from ${bootenv_dev} ...; " \
        "env import -t ${loadbootenv_addr} $filesize\0" \
    "bootenv_existence_test=test -e ${bootenv_dev} 0 /${bootenv}\0" \
    "setbootenv=if env run bootenv_existence_test; then " \
            "if env run loadbootenv; then " \
                "env run importbootenv; " \
            "fi; " \
        "fi; \0" \
    "sd_loadbootenv=set bootenv_dev mmc && " \
            "run setbootenv \0" \
    "usb_loadbootenv=set bootenv_dev usb && usb start && run setbootenv \0" \
    "preboot=if test $modeboot = sdboot; then " \
            "run sd_loadbootenv; " \
            "echo Checking if uenvcmd is set ...; " \
            "if test -n $uenvcmd; then " \
                "echo Running uenvcmd ...; " \
                "run uenvcmd; " \
            "fi; " \
        "fi; \0" \
    "norboot=echo Copying FIT from NOR flash to RAM... && " \
        "cp.b ${nor_flash_off} ${load_addr} ${fit_size} && " \
        "bootm ${load_addr}\0" \
    "kernel_image=uImage\0" \
    "kernel_load_address=0x2080000\0"   \
    "ramdisk_image=uramdisk.image.gz\0" \
    "ramdisk_load_address=0x4000000\0"  \
    "devicetree_image=devicetree.dtb\0" \
    "devicetree_load_address=0x2000000\0"   \
    "sdboot=if mmcinfo; then "  \
            "echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && "  \
            "load mmc 0 ${kernel_load_address} ${kernel_image} && " \
            "load mmc 0 ${devicetree_load_address} ${devicetree_image} && " \
            "bootm ${kernel_load_address} - ${devicetree_load_address}; "   \
        "fi\0"  \
    "jtagboot=echo TFTPing FIT to RAM... && " \
        "tftpboot ${load_addr} ${fit_image} && " \
        "bootm ${load_addr}\0" \
    "usbboot=if usb start; then " \
            "echo Copying FIT from USB to RAM... && " \
            "load usb 0 ${load_addr} ${fit_image} && " \
            "bootm ${load_addr}; fi\0" \
        DFU_ALT_INFO
#endif
```

In addition, if needed, I can share other configuration files used.

If you think stackoverflow is NOT the right place where to ask this kind of questions please, suggest me where I can do that and I will move to the other forum.
Thank you for your time reading the question.

Comment: have you come across this https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2015-August/223137.html

Comment: @Prabhakar, where? In which file?

Comment: if  zynq_zybo_defconfig used for your pynq board yes, look into the makefile depending on what command you give to build, also you need to look CONFIG_SPL_FS_LOAD_PAYLOAD_NAME in  include/configs/zynq-common.h

Comment: That solved the problem!! Answer to the question so I vote up (the right file, of course, was `zynq_artyz7_defconfig`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [link](https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2015-August/223137.html), if `zynq_artyz7_defconfig` used for your pynq board yes, look into the makefile depending on what command you give to build, also you need to look CONFIG_SPL_FS_LOAD_PAYLOAD_NAME in include/configs/zynq-common.h